# Can't read the text from textbox

Tags: vb.net

The value in the variables is empty.here is my code:

```
        Private Sub button1_click()

        Dim uname As String
        uname = Request.Form("user_name")
        Dim pword As String
        pword = Request.Form("password")
        If uname = "admin" And pword = "admin" Then
            MsgBox("OK")
        Else
            MsgBox("NOT")
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of want you want exactly, but if just to get the text in an textbox...

```
    Private Sub button1_click()

    Dim uname As String
    uname = TextBoxName.Text
    Dim pword As String
    pword = TextBoxName.Text
    If uname = "admin" And pword = "admin" Then
        MsgBox("OK")
    Else
        MsgBox("NOT")
    End If
End Sub
```